# Solving dice problem using the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: probability, dice, inclusion-exclusion

We roll a die ten times. What's the probability of getting all the six different numbers of the dice?

If $A_i$ is the event of getting at least of the numbers from $i=1$ to $6$. What the problem is asking is $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6)$ .  So I guess I will get this probability if I develop the exclusion inclusion formula for the union of different events. Is the starting point to find $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5 \cup A_6 \cup A_7 \cup A_8 \cup A_9 \cup A_{10})$ ? Where $A_i$ would be here each throw of the dice?

We were asked to do it by the inclusion exclusion principle,as the tittle of the problem says.
TIA for any hint or answer.

Comment: Well, as you suggest, inclusion exclusion is a good idea.  How have you started?

Comment: Well, look up inclusion exclusion.  work some examples.  This one is completely standard and the examples from your text, or those that you can find online, will follow the same pattern.

Comment: What the problem is asking $P(1\cap 2\cap 3\cap 4\cap 5\cap 6 )$. So I guess I will get this if I develop the formula. Is the starting point $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5\cup A_6\cup A_7\cup A_8\cup A_9\cup  A_{10})?$ Where $A_i$ is any number from 1 to 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were no restrictions, there would be six possible outcomes for each of the ten throws, so there are $6^{10}$ possible sequences of throws.  From these, we must exclude those in which fewer than six outcomes occur.

There are $\binom{6}{k}$ ways to exclude $k$ of the $6$ outcomes and $(6 - k)^{10}$ possible sequences involving only the remaining $6 - k$ possible outcomes of a die throw.  By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways all six outcomes can occur when a six-sided die is tossed ten times is
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{6} (-1)^k\binom{6}{k}(6 - k)^{10} = \binom{6}{0}6^{10} - \binom{6}{1}5^{10} + \binom{6}{2}4^{10} - \binom{6}{3}3^{10} + \binom{6}{4}2^{10} - \binom{6}{5}1^{10} + \binom{6}{6}0^{10}$$

Comment: Yes, this gets us $16435440$ and the algorithm scales nicely with big $n$.

Comment: @n-f-taussig. Thanks for your answer.I wanted to ask you if are nonsensical comments allowed in this forum? I'm referring to Zhuoran He, 1)Since the number is not nice-looking, this problem does not look like a math homework
2)And I also hope someone can give a polynomial-time algorithm for big n
3)Your n is not big, so basically you can do it anyway
4)I'm wondering if this is a #P-complete problem

Comment: Well, I was just a bit unsatisfied with my way of doing it, even though I had the answer. Now I know how to do it more efficiently. Now I remove that part.

Comment: @falcon16 With regard to the seemingly offhand remark about homework, there is an expectation at this site that when you pose a question that you tell us your own thoughts about the problem.  You are permitted to ask questions about your homework.  However, you are much more likely to obtain helpful responses if you tell us what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck. Questions that do not include that information tend to be closed.  As for the remarks about the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle and the algorithm, I interpreted them as calls for alternative solutions.

Comment: @n-f-taussig What is the need to remove alternative solutions and common sense expectations?
The only answer is that they were unrespectful. This attitude breaks the rules of this forum.

Comment: @falcon16 If you find comments disrespectful, then you should bring it up with the person who made the remarks.  If you encounter abusive remarks, flag the comment or answer for moderator attention.  I do not understand what you mean by remove alternative solutions.  There are different ways to solve this problem, as the answers you have received make clear.  While the answer by Zhouran He is correct, I answered your question because you made clear that you were seeking a solution that uses the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Thanks N. F. Taussig for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can also be solved using classification. Let $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_6$ be the number of dices showing $1, 2,\ldots,6$, respectively. Define the set

$$A_{n,r}=\{(n_1,\ldots,n_6)_{\,}|_{\,}n_1\geq r,\cdots,n_6\geq r, n_1+\cdots+n_6=n\}.$$

Then the number of ways to let all numbers $1,2,\ldots, 6$ appear at least once in $10$ dice throws is

$$S=\sum_{(n_1,\ldots,n_6)\in A_{10,1}}\frac{10!}{n_1!\cdots n_6!}.$$

Use this number to divide by $6^{10}$, you get the probability. There are ${9\choose 5}=126$ elements in $A_{10,1}$. We don't need to enumerate them one by one. Many are equivalent up to permulations. So one can divide them into $5$ classes:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mbox{No.} & \mbox{Class} & \mbox{Count} & n_1!\cdots n_6!\\
\hline
1 & 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 & 6 & 120\\
2 & 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 & 30 & 48\\
3 & 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1 & 15 & 36\\
4 & 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 & 60 & 24\\
5 & 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1 & 15 & 16\\
\hline
- & \mbox{Total} & 126 & -\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

In every class, the denominator $n_1!\cdots n_6!$ is the same. Therefore

$$S=10!\times\left(\frac{6}{120}+\frac{30}{48}+\cdots+\frac{15}{16}\right)=16435440.$$

Then the probability is $$P=\frac{S}{6^{10}}=\frac{38045}{139968}\approx 0.2718.$$

Comment: Why is a polynomial-time algorithm for big n needed?

Comment: I see, it makes a lot of sense. It's a nice looking answer.